# 2d Platformer game stone changing size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a platformer game. In the platformer game has a moving platform that makes everything it touches its transform's child while it touches it. Interestingly, whenever a stone(A movable object with a rigidbody and a polygon collider) touches the moving platform, the stone's scale goes haywire. Even though the scale reads the same on the transform component, it appears to be larger or smaller than it really is when touching it. When it stops touching the platform, the stone appears normal. Can anyone help me. Thank you.

This is the moving platform script that moves the platform around.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveTwoTransforms : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform pointA;
    public Transform pointB;
    public bool HasReachedA;
    public bool HasReacedB;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = pointA.position;
        HasReacedB = true;
        HasReachedA = false;

        StartCoroutine(GlideAround());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public IEnumerator GlideAround()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            while (HasReachedA == false)
            {
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

                transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, pointA.position, 0.01f);
                if ((Mathf.Abs(Vector2.Distance(pointA.position, transform.position)) < 0.01f))
                {
                    HasReacedB = false;
                    HasReachedA = true;
                }
            }

            while (HasReacedB == false)
            {
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, pointB.position, 0.01f);

                if ((Mathf.Abs(Vector2.Distance(pointB.position, transform.position)) < 0.01f))
                {
                    HasReacedB = true;
                    HasReachedA = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if((collision.gameObject.tag == "Stone"|| collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") && (collision.transform.position.y - collision.transform.lossyScale.y / 2 >= transform.position.y))
        {
            collision.transform.parent = transform;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        collision.transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

This is the stone script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RememberPositions : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 StartingPosition;
    public Vector3 StartingRotation;
    public Vector3 StartingScale;

    float StartRotation;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartingPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, 0);
        StartingRotation = new Vector3(0, 0, transform.position.z);
        StartingScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.localScale = StartingScale;
    }
}
```

There are no errors whatsoever and the rigidbody seems to be changing to the shape of the stone. Can anyone please specify the correct code I should use? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your moving platform is scaled, your stone will get scaled too. There are workarounds shown [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/147816/how-to-avoid-scaling-heritage-when-parenting.html) to avoid this issue. One of them is adding a child `GameObject` to the platform, and moving the collision handling from the platform to that child.